# corresponding to Java wildcard generics in C#

Tags: c#, java

Hi what is corresponding code in C# for following three lines in java

```
import java.util.Map;
import static net.oauth.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER;

Collections.<Map.Entry<?, ?>>emptySet()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

`Enumerable.Empty<KeyValuePair<Object, Object>>()`